# Fitting pandas Data Frames to Scikit-Learn’s model without using additional libraries or methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

On the one hand, [people say](https://www.quora.com/How-does-python-pandas-go-along-with-scikit-learn-library) **pandas** goes along great with **scikit-learn**. For example, pandas series objects fit well with sklearn models [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwnaUVt6VVE). On the other hand, there is **sklearn-pandas** providing a bridge between Scikit-Learn’s machine learning methods and pandas-style Data Frames which means there is a need for such libraries. Moreover, some people, for example, convert pandas data frames to numpy array for fitting a model.

I wonder whether it's possible to combine **pandas** and **scikit-learn** without any additional methods and libraries. My problem is that whenever I fit my data set to sklearn models in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

d = {'x': np.linspace(1., 100., 20), 'y': np.linspace(1., 10., 20)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2)

trainX = train['x']
trainY = train['y']

lin_svm = SVC(kernel='linear').fit(trainX, trainY)
```

I receive an error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 19    10.000000
0      1.000000
17     9.052632
18     9.526316
12     6.684211
11     6.210526
16     8.578947
14     7.631579
10     5.736842
7      4.315789
8      4.789474
2      1.947368
13     7.157895
1      1.473684
6      3.842105
3      2.421053
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

As far as I understand that's because of the data structure. However, there are few examples on the internet using similar code without any problems.

Comment: Usually when and pandas and sklearn fight a simple `trainY.reshape()` fixes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might want to do is a **regression** and not a **classification**.

Think about it, to do a classification, you need either a **binary** output or a **multiclass one**. In your case you give **continuous** data to your *classifier*.

If you trace back your error and dig a little bit deeper in `sklearn`'s implementation of the method `.fit()` you will find the following function:

```
def check_classification_targets(y):
"""Ensure that target y is of a non-regression type.

Only the following target types (as defined in type_of_target) are allowed:
    'binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 
    'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences'

Parameters
----------
y : array-like
"""
y_type = type_of_target(y)
if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput', 
        'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y)
```

And the doc string of the function `type_of_target` is :

```
def type_of_target(y):
"""Determine the type of data indicated by target `y`

Parameters
----------
y : array-like

Returns
-------
target_type : string
    One of:
    * 'continuous': `y` is an array-like of floats that are not all
      integers, and is 1d or a column vector.
    * 'continuous-multioutput': `y` is a 2d array of floats that are
      not all integers, and both dimensions are of size > 1.
    * 'binary': `y` contains <= 2 discrete values and is 1d or a column
      vector.
    * 'multiclass': `y` contains more than two discrete values, is not a
      sequence of sequences, and is 1d or a column vector.
    * 'multiclass-multioutput': `y` is a 2d array that contains more
      than two discrete values, is not a sequence of sequences, and both
      dimensions are of size > 1.
    * 'multilabel-indicator': `y` is a label indicator matrix, an array
      of two dimensions with at least two columns, and at most 2 unique
      values.
    * 'unknown': `y` is array-like but none of the above, such as a 3d
      array, sequence of sequences, or an array of non-sequence objects.
```

In your case `type_of_target(trainY)=='continuous' and then it raises a`ValueError`in the function`check_classification_targets()`.

---

**Conclusion** :

- If you want to perform a **classification**, change your target `y`. (eg. use a binary vector)
- If you want to keep your *continuous data* perform a **regression**. Use [`svm.SVR`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html).